# jQuery Animate Width freezes iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

Using this code to toggle the width of `<div class="artists"></div>` will freeze the browser on an iPad. Is there a work around for this? I use the latest jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   $("a:nth-child(4)").click(function () {
   $(".artists").animate({width:'toggle'},0);
   $('.blur').toggleClass('blurbody'); 
   });
</script>
```

It works correctly on a normal computer browser, just not on an iPad (Chrome or Safari). You can view the site at saint57records.com and click on the artists icon on the left.

Comment: how many `artists` elements are present?

Comment: Why are you setting the width to a string value?

Comment: It's to change it between being hidden and showing 100% width

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jquery function after your selection:

```
$("#targetElement").toggle();
```

Since you wish to change between invisible and 100% width, this should work !

Comment: That works better, but it is still freezing the iPad for about 10 seconds, instead of about 30 seconds

Comment: I think pre-loading the content of this div in the background might help ! 
Whenever there are images etc. if content is pre-loaded, the response of toggle visibility becomes much faster, at least for the first time. This might avoid freezing !
There are many jQuery preloader plugins like this:
code.google.com/p/jloader/

Answer (score 0):

To toggle the width you should so something like this:

```
<script>
   $("a:nth-child(4)").click(function () {
   var targetWidth = (someBoolean) ? '100px' : '300px';
   $(".artists").animate({width:targetWidth},0);
   $('.blur').toggleClass('blurbody'); 
   });
</script>
```